# Knockout js some parts does not render

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have a very weird knockout js problem. What happens is that only the first tag in each div is rendered to the DOM, the others just ... don't. The werdest part is this: it does not produce any errors and the rest of the dom renders correctly, secondly it happens most but not all the time? Any guesses?

The template that is being rendered is this:

```
<div class="row">        
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.topRows()[0].text() + $data.topRows()[1].text()" />            
        <input data-bind="value: $data.topRows()[0].inputText"  /> <!-- this fails to go into the dom sometimes and every row past the first span and inside this div -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.topRows()[1].text()" />    <!-- this is renderdd -->        
        <input data-bind="text: $data.topRows()[1].inputText" /> <!-- this is not -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this is not much to go on but well, I am speechless. RequireJs is used to require all the files.

Comment: Is `inputText` an observable?

Comment: yes and I can switch around the observables so inputText first and then text. Then the inputText shows but the tag with .text does not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various problems in your proposed snippet:

- `span` elements don't work too well when self-closing, use `<span data-bind="..."></span>` instead;
- you don't close the first comment correctly
- as @ilya mentioned you probably want the `value` binding for inputs
- you have a typo for the second input, it starts with `<inputdata-bind...` (missing a space there

If I fix those four problems your code [will work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/VKgKG/).

Comment: it was the span that was incorrect. The comments I added for stackoverflow, valuebinding well I was trying around and type well ...  my bad. Sorry for such incorrect question. I thought I had tried with the span change but well obviously not, thanks a million for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `value` binding instead of `text` for `<input>`

```
<span data-bind="text: $data.topRows()[0].text() + $data.topRows()[1].text()" />            
<input data-bind="value: $data.topRows()[0].inputText"  />
```

and

```
<span data-bind="text: $data.topRows()[1].text()" />        
<input data-bind="value: $data.topRows()[1].inputText" />
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQv78/)